# Pg_Search don't filter model referenced to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

I'm renewing a small library app and my search filter (pg_search) doesn't work with a model that is referenced with another (in this case, model Book as User references, for each user to have it's own set of books).
But if i delete the references, the search works... In the case that if the books were available to every user but that's not the purpose.
What am i missing?
Thanks in advance for any help.

> Book.rb

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  include PgSearch::Model

  pg_search_scope :search_by_full_name, against: [:title, :author],
  using: { tsearch: { prefix: true } }

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :author, presence: true
end
```

> User.rb

```
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

   has_many :books
end
```

> books_controller.rb

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

    def index
      
        if params[:term].present?
          @books = Book.search_by_full_name(params[:term])
         
        else
          @books = Book.all
        end
  end
  
    def show
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      
    end
  
    def new
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @book = Book.new
      
    end
  
    def create
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @book = Book.new(book_params)
      @book.user = @user
      
      if @book.save
        redirect_to user_books_path
        flash[:notice] = 'Success. Your book was added to the Library'
      else
        render "new"
        flash[:notice] = 'Book not created. Please try again'
  
      end
    end
  
    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      
    end
  
    def update
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @book.update(book_params)
      
      redirect_to user_book_path
    end
  
    def destroy
      @book = Book.find(params[:id])
      @book.destroy
      
      redirect_to user_books_path
    end
  
    private
  
    def book_params
      params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :photo, :comments)
    end
  
end
```

> _search_book.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag user_books_path(current_user.id, @book), method: :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'term', params[:term], placeholder: "Enter title or author" %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Search!' %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: when `@book` is assigned this path `user_books_path(current_user.id, @book)` will submit to `show` action. change it to `user_books_path(current_user.id)`

Comment: @Alex I already tried that (on the search_book_form), it gives me all the books still, instead of the searched one

Comment: can you post what the log looks like when you submit the form

Answer (score 0):

It's solved... I was using current_user on the views instead of applying all the method on the controller and on the view leave it with only the model instance.
Thanks everyone